# Filtering NSArray with NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate

Its my code :

```
-(NSArray *)searchTeamsWithPlayerPharse:(NSMutableArray *)teams phrase:(NSString *)phrase

{

   NSPredicate *searchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"rel_Players.fullName CONTAINS[c] %@" ,phrase];
   NSArray *searchResult = [teams filteredArrayUsingPredicate:searchPredicate];


    return searchResult ;
}
```

It is not working. In array I have Team objects. Team has relationship with players and i want filtr with this relathionship and find only teams with players have pharse in fullName. How to change this NSPredicate

Comment: Is `rel_Players` a 1-to-many relationship?

Comment: Yes. 1 team has many players.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ANY` operator should work:

```
NSPredicate *searchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY rel_Players.fullName CONTAINS[c] %@" ,phrase];
```

Some additional remarks:

- a `rel_` prefix is unusual and unnecessary: the plural form players is enough and the underscore can be omitted because the beginning of a new word is marked by an uppercase character (camel case).
- The method does not need to take a mutable array argument. This restricts the use cases to arguments of type `NSMutableArray`. If you change the parameter type to `NSArray *` you can use instances of both `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray`.
- The method does not work on the instance context: It does not have a single access to `self`. You can make a function out of it or – I would prefer that – make it a method of `NSArray`.

Taking this together:

```
@interface NSArray(TeamPlayerAddition)
-(NSArray *)teamsWithPlayerPharse:(NSString *)phrase
@end

@implementation NSArray(TeamPlayerAddition)
-(NSArray *)teamsWithPlayerPharse:(NSString *)phrase
{
  NSPredicate *searchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY rel_Players.fullName CONTAINS[c] %@" ,phrase];
  return [self filteredArrayUsingPredicate:searchPredicate];
}
@end
```

Comment: Why would you add a method to `NSArray` that relates to a single class that has nothing to do with `NSArray`?  Add the method as a class method on `Team`, if anything.

Comment: It has to do something with the array. self points to the array. The array is the only link to any object. Having a dedicated extension it is not said, that it has a global meaning.